# Recreate a figure with PGFplot (plot without data)

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Is there a way to recreate a plot from a source into my own LaTeX format without having the data? I want to recreate these two images (jus the lines, not the arrow or text):
[image]

And I want it to look something like this:
[image]

Code for my figure:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name = ax1, width = 0.7\textwidth, height = 0.4\textwidth,  every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
    axis lines = left, no markers, legend cell align={left},  grid,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 7, 
    xlabel = Voltage (V), ylabel = Current (A),]
    \addplot [color=red!70!black] table [x=V2, y=A2, mark = none, col sep = semicolon] {tempeffect.csv};\addlegendentry{Warm}   
    \addplot [color=blue!70!black] table [x=V1, y=A1, mark = none, col sep = semicolon] {tempeffect.csv};\addlegendentry{Cold}  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Illustration of the effect of temperature on the IV curve of a cSi module}
\label{fig:ivcurvetemp}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What is in `tempeffect.csv`?

Comment: The three curves in the first are similar to functions of the form `\addplot {6 - exp((x-45)/3)};`.

Comment: You will need to generate a table with datapoints. Enter "digitise given plot" in your favourite web search engine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. tempeffect.csv has x and y coordinates for my graph. Unfortunately, I don't have the coordinates for the figures I want to recreate.

Comment: @AlexG I see that there are a lot. What's your favorite plot digitiser?

Comment: I have no idea. Perhaps you know the analytical expressions that produced the curves? You wouldn't need a plot digitizer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal based on Torbjørn T. suggestion applied multiple way. (@Torbjørn T. I'll be happy to remove this if you want to post an answer.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name = ax1, width = 0.7\textwidth, height = 0.4\textwidth,  every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
    axis lines = left, no markers, legend cell align={left},  grid,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 60, ymin = 0, ymax = 7, 
    xlabel = Module Output Voltage, ylabel = Current Output]
    \addplot[domain=0:60,samples=60,smooth,blue] {6 - exp((x-45)/3)};
    \addplot[domain=0:60,samples=60,smooth,blue!60] {5.5 - exp((x-45)/3)};
    \addplot[domain=0:60,samples=60,smooth,blue!20] {5 - exp((x-45)/3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name = ax1, width = 0.7\textwidth, height = 0.4\textwidth,  every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
    axis lines = left, no markers, legend cell align={left},  grid,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 600, ymin = 0, ymax = 20,restrict y to domain=-2:20, 
    xlabel = Module Output Voltage, ylabel = Current Output]
    \addplot[domain=0:590,samples=60,smooth,gray!50] {18 -
    min(exp((x-420)/30),18)};
    \addplot[domain=0:590,samples=120,smooth,blue!50] {
    6 - min(exp((x-120)/20),6) +
    6 - min(exp((x-300)/20),6) +
    6 - min(exp((x-470)/20),6)
    };
    \node[align=center,blue!50,font=\small] at (axis cs:240,8) {SHADED\\ OUTPUT};
    \node[align=center,gray!50,font=\small] at (axis cs:540,16) {NORMAL\\ OUTPUT};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better than the original +1.

Comment: Nah, no point. Clever idea for that "shaded output" function.